# Forcing a UIImagePickerController to open a square camera with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I've been struggling to find a way to launch a UIImagePickerController with a square live view, and getting it to take a square picture. The code I have right now to launch the camera is below

```
func takePicture() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
        println("Button capture")
        var imag = UIImagePickerController()
        imag.delegate = self
        imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        //imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage];
        imag.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    let selectedImage : UIImage = image
    //var tempImage:UIImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage

    var newImage: UIImage = resizeImageWithImage(selectedImage, size: CGSize(width: 320, height: 568))

    datImage.image=newImage

    let paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDir: NSString = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString

    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let now:NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
    let theDate = dateFormat.stringFromDate(now)

    //Make Photo URL

    self.photoURL = NSString(format: "/%@.png", theDate)

    //save resized image

    let pathToFullPhoto: NSString = documentsDir.stringByAppendingString(self.photoURL)

    let pngFull: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)
    pngFull.writeToFile(pathToFullPhoto, atomically: true)



    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

triggered with:
    `self.takePicture()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this question? Ive got the camera to open with very few lines of code (which is great) but i only want the square option to be available

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the `cameraOverlayView` property? This seems like it is what you are looking for.

[Link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)

You then need to crop the image once you receive it, since the overlay view won't actually do the cropping. To crop, simply get the image and draw it into a rect that is smaller, based on the size of the "opening" in your `cameraOverlayView`.